# Firing events within a plug-in architecture vs single application

Tags: c#, events, plugins, event-handling

I am getting stumped with my plug-in architecture that I am trying to develop with respect to events.  I can do this just fine, in a single application: (Obviously this is a very simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish, and if this were my code there are easier ways to accomplish this, just try to follow the logic ;)

```
public Form1()
{
    public event EventHandler OnValueOver5Chars;

    Main()
    {
        OnValueOver5Chars+= new EventHandler(WarnUser);
        ....
    }

    private void textBox_Changed( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if( sender.Text.count() > 5 )
            OnValueOver5Chars(sender, e); // WORKS HERE
    }

    private void WarnUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, now I have a plug-in architecture, where the plugin implements an interface which houses my event:

```
// Interface.cs
public interface IPlugin
{
    event EventHandler OnValueOver5Chars;
    ...
}

// Plugin1.cs
public class Plugin1 : IPlugin
{
    public event EventHandler OnValueOver5Chars;

    Plugin1()
    {
        OnValueOver5Chars += new EventHandler(Plugin1WarnUser);
    }

    private void Plugin1WarnUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
}

// Form.cs
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Plugin1.dll");
        Type myType = SampleAssembly.GetTypes()[0];
        if (myType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IPlugin)))
        {
            IPlugin myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType) as IPlugin;
            myInstance.OnValueOver5Chars(this, new EventArgs());
            // Compiler Error CS0079 - The event 'event' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
        }
}
```

????

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to hook up an event to another event, and that won't work. You need to hook the plug-ins event to a method/delegate. Once you do that, have the method/delegate call the other event.

```
myInstance.OnValueOver5Chars += OnValueOver5CharsFunc;
...
/*In Form1*/
void OnValueOver5CharsFunc( object sender, EventArgs args )
{
    OnValueOver5Chars( sender, args );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Events in C# have the property that they are not "callable" directly as methods (or as such as delegates) outside of the class where they are defined.

In your first example you are calling the event from within the class in which you define it. In the second example, however, you are trying to call `OnValueOver5Chars` from outside the class - hence the error.

To solve this you could consider adding a method to your `IPlugin` interface (e.g. `ValueOver5Chars`) that performs `OnValueOver5Chars`. Note that it is more common to name the event `ValueOver5Chars` (say), and provide a method `OnValueOver5Chars` to raise it (i.e. the other way round). See for example the Windows Forms Button [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) and its `Click` event.